# Cutting off from backtrace the steps coming from particular libraries

Tags: ruby, backtrace

Sometimes, we use libraries that are pretty much well debugged and are usually not a cause of an error. Still, these libraries can return errors due to our misuse of their API. In such case, the steps internal to these libraries show up within the backtrace of an error, which are just garbage from the point of view of the programmers using the library, and make it difficult to spot the cause of the error. Even some methods in the core Ruby insert some internal steps into the backtrace. For example, whenever you see a backtrace involving `Enumerable#inject`, there is always `Enumerable#each` being called from it, which shows up in the backtrace and is annoying.

1. What is a good way to remove from the backtrace the steps internal to certain given libraries? I am currently dong it by parsing the backtrace and filtering it by the file name. Is there a better way to do it?
2. When you are writing a library by yourself, is there a good way to suppress the internal steps appearing in a backtrace involving a method call that uses the library? An obvious way might be to insert a pair of `rescue` and `raise` for every method that is to be used from outside of the library, but that does not seem right.

Comment: `Enumerable#reject` FTW :)

Comment: Looks like aspects (I prefer [aquarium](https://github.com/deanwampler/Aquarium) for ruby) is what you are looking for. See e. g. [“Wrapping” an Exception](http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/examples.html) (scroll down a couple of screens.)

Answer (score 1):

Well...

1. There isn't really a better way to filter. If you can get the full filepath for the backtrace, though, you can filter by directory which can rule out all stdlibs and gems. Beyond that, it's more trouble than it's worth.
2. There is a much better solution for this. However, it requires that you catch all exception thrown by Ruby in your library, and then rethrow them after doing this (also do this to all your own excpetions). So wrap all your method with this:

   ```
   begin
     ...
   rescue Exception
     e = $!  
     e.set_backtrace(caller(nesting_level))
     raise e
   end
   ```

   The `nesting_level` is how many methods of this library the current method was called from. If it was called directly from  user code, put 0. If it was called by one method that was called in user code, put in 1, and so on.

Comment: I can't exactly get what you suggest in 2. Can you elaborate on that?